# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop Dell Inspiron 3147 using USB stick?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb, laptop

I've downloaded and tried to run Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on laptop Dell Inspiron 3147, but it freezes while starting from USB stick.

What is the correct way to install Ubuntu on my laptop?

Comment: found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1341925 and this http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19595872

Comment: followed this instruction and installed ubuntu just fine http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported, no need to disable secure boot. The only one problem - PC hangs when shut-down/restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wait if you want.

The only thing thing that blacklisting these modules does is revert the linux kernel to using PIO instead of DMA, which are both ways that data is sent between the CPU and hardware.

Differences between the two is explained here: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-dma-and-pio/

I can personally say that you can still get a pleasurably usable system using this blackilisting method, as i am writing this response from my dell 3147. But like I started off with, you could wait for patched support.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with Ubuntu 14.10, it has been reported to work out of the box with this machine:

[Dell Inspiron 11 3000 Series budget 2-in-1 convertible review](http://liliputing.com/2014/10/dell-inspiron-11-3000-series-budget-2-1-convertible-review.html)

Answer (score 0):

normal shutdown and suspend functions can be had by blacklisting the DMA kernel modules so they dont load at boot. this also allows suspending and awakening when closing/opening the lid.

do this by going to etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf with your text editor and adding these line of text:
blacklist dw_dmac
blacklist dw_dmac_core

and save with superuser privileges. you should now be able to properly shudown/suspend.
now only thing left to fix is brightness control which im still searching for.

Comment: is it dangerous fix? may my system become unbootable? what do I loose adding these lines? Probably I should just wait for the next Ubuntu release and issue will be fixed there?